# Couchbase rebalance keeps failing because of buckets_shutdown_wait_failed

Tags: couchbase, bucket

I've updated couchbase cluster from version `2.5.1 to 3.0.3`. Upgrade was performed node by node by removing one node from cluster, upgrading it and add it again.
All was working but not the DCP upgrade. I've found in `error.log` that we have some "Weird `vbucket_move_done`" for a `proximic2 bucket`, which isn't used for a while now.
So I've deleted this bucket and try to rebalance but it failed. It was few ours ago and rebalance keeps failing:

```
Rebalance exited with reason {buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
[{'ns_1@cb6.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}},
{'ns_1@cb2.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}},
{'ns_1@cb1.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}},
{'ns_1@cb0.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}}]}
    ns_orchestrator002  ns_1@cb2.xxx.com    20:42:59 - Fri Jun 19, 2015
Failed to wait deletion of some buckets on some nodes: [{'ns_1@cb6.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}},
{'ns_1@cb2.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}},
{'ns_1@cb1.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}},
{'ns_1@cb0.xxx.com',
{'EXIT',
{old_buckets_shutdown_wait_failed,
["proximic2"]}}}]
```

I'm a bit blocked right now. I've tried to create this `proximic2` bucket, but I've got information that it already exists. However this bucket is not visible in web GUI or cli. Couchbase runs on debians 7.8. All nodes are in version 3.0.3.

Marek

Comment: Your best bet to finding an answer in this case is to file a bug and upload your logs to issues.couchbase.com. In order to get all of the logs in an upload-able for click on the logs tab in the Admin Console and then click on the collect info tab.